# logstash array of key value pairs

Tags: filter, logstash

I am using logstash and I would like to know if there is a way to handle the following:

Using the xml filter I am able to extract a properties field

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<event logger="RemoteEventReceiver1" timestamp="2016-07-21T12:39:04.0607421-05:00" level="DEBUG" thread="26" domain="/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131135962764935573" username="TOOTHLESS\dvdp4">
    <message>Test nessage</message>
    <properties>
        <data name="log4net:HostName" value="Toothless"/>
        <data name="log4net:Customer" value="Bob"/>
    </properties>
</event>
```

that looks like this

```
"properties" => [
    [0] {
        "data" => [
            [0] {
                 "name" => "HostName",
                "value" => "Toothless"
            },
            [1] {
                 "name" => "Customer",
                "value" => "Bob"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

how can I convert it to this?

```
“propertiesParsed” => {
    “HostName” => “Toothless”,
    “Customer” => “Bob”
    }
```

*** UPDATE ADDING CONFIG AND DATA FILE ***

```
input {
    file {
        type => "log4net"
        path => ["D:/temp/MR4SPO.log"]
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "nul"
    }
}
filter 
{   
    mutate {
        # remove xml prefices in the message field
        gsub => [ "message", "log4net:", "" ]
    }

    xml {
        source => "message"
        target => "log4net"
        add_field => {
            log4net_message => "%{[log4net][message]}"
            # "[log4net][messagetest]" => [log4net][message]
            # xxx => "%{[log4net][properties][0][data]}"
        }       
        remove_field => "message"
    }

    # get json message from log4net
    if [log4net_message] =~ "^LS:\s{" {
        ruby { code => "event['log4net_message'] = event['log4net_message'][3..-1]" }
        json { 
            source => "log4net_message" 
            # target => "log4net_json" 
        }
        mutate {
            add_field => { forMQ => true }
        }
    }

    mutate {
        remove_field => "log4net_message"
    }
}   

# output logs to console and to elasticsearch
output {
    if [forMQ] {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }

    # elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }

}
```

*** DATA FILE ***

```
<log4net:event logger="SPMRDLAdd_InWeb.Services.RemoteEventReceiver1" timestamp="2016-07-21T12:39:03.0607421-05:00" level="DEBUG" thread="26" domain="/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131135962764935573" username="TOOTHLESS\dvdp4"><log4net:message>My test one</log4net:message><log4net:properties><log4net:data name="log4net:HostName" value="Toothless" /></log4net:properties></log4net:event>
<log4net:event logger="SPMRDLAdd_InWeb.Services.RemoteEventReceiver1" timestamp="2016-07-21T12:39:04.0607421-05:00" level="DEBUG" thread="26" domain="/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131135962764935573" username="TOOTHLESS\dvdp4"><log4net:message>LS: { "name" : "file123.jpg", "size" : 50 }</log4net:message><log4net:properties><log4net:data name="log4net:HostName" value="Toothless" /></log4net:properties></log4net:event>
```

Comment: Can you show your conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add that `ruby` filter:

```
...
ruby {
    code => "
    event['propertiesParsed'] = {}
    for value in event['log4net']['properties']
        for data in value['data']
            event['propertiesParsed'][data['name']] = data['value']
        end
    end
    "
}
...
```